# Layouting, not able to achieve

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I would like to create this layout :
[image]

This is the code i used :

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ans_bg_normal"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding25"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            >
            <com.app.quizjeetho.Fonts.TextView_Bold
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ans_circle_normal"
                android:id="@+id/option1_a"
                />

            <com.app.quizjeetho.Fonts.TextView_Bold
                android:id="@+id/option1"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="asdsdddadsadasdasdsadasdsadddsf"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

I am getting this output from this :

[image]

The text is overlapping, how do I solve this?

Comment: in second textview use  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/option1_a"

Comment: for better result use LinearLayout with orientation Horizontal
and set layour_weight on both Textview

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your `RelativeLayout` to make it work

```
<com.app.quizjeetho.Fonts.TextView_Bold
    android:id="@+id/option1"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/option1_a"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="asdsdddadsadasdasdsadasdsadddsf" />
```

Aligning this layout to the end of the first layout will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try to set weight like this & see is it working or not:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ans_bg_normal"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding25"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:weightSum="1">

            <com.app.quizjeetho.Fonts.TextView_Bold
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ans_circle_normal"
                android:id="@+id/option1_a"
                 android:layout_weight=".3"/>

            <com.app.quizjeetho.Fonts.TextView_Bold
                android:id="@+id/option1"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="asdsdddadsadasdasdsadasdsadddsf"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_weight=".7"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think getting separate background images for every option might help or you can take two different images for background

1. for question number and
2. for background of your option layout.